# Reordering Python two lists without disturbing the compliments between the lists

Tags: python, list

I have two Python lists:

```
numbers=[11, 12, 13, 10, 14, 2, 3] 
suits=['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C']
```

These lists are in a specific order, i.e. 11 goes with D and 2 goes with C etc.

I'm trying to write a function that will rearrange the order of these lists without disturbing the compliments (i.e. the 11 does with D bits). The function has an argument that determines how the list is ordered. The first should order the lists numerically, from highest to lowest and the second should order them by instances of suit occurrence, from most to least occurrences in the list (So there are 5 D's and 2 C's in this example, so in this case they are already in the correct order).

The structure of this function is pasted below but I'm struggling with the actual ordering parts of the code. Does anybody have any suggestions of how to do this?

```
def order_cards(order_by=suit):
    '''
    order_by has two arguments, either suit or number
    if suit: order by occurances of suit from largest to smallest
    if number: order by decreasing number
    '''
    if order_by='number':
        for i in range(len(numbers)): #Probably should iterate over the lists
            #code for ordering cards
            return ordered_cards
    elif order_by='suit':
        count=collections.Counter(suits) #This code count occurrences of suits
        #code to order by number of suits
        return ordered_cards
    else:
        return '{} is not \'suit\' or \'number\''.format(order_by)
```

Comment: if you want to keep the *compliments* why not combine the two lists into a list of tuples or a dict ?

Comment: `zip` function is your friend here.

Comment: zip them into tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you want something like this:

```
>>> numbers=[11, 12, 13, 10, 14, 2, 3]
>>> suits=['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C']
>>> 
>>> t = zip(numbers,suits)
>>> t
[(11, 'D'), (12, 'D'), (13, 'D'), (10, 'D'), (14, 'D'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'C')]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(t, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)#sort t by numbers from highest to lowest
[(14, 'D'), (13, 'D'), (12, 'D'), (11, 'D'), (10, 'D'), (3, 'C'), (2, 'C')]
>>> sorted(t, key=itemgetter(1)) #sort t by suits
[(2, 'C'), (3, 'C'), (11, 'D'), (12, 'D'), (13, 'D'), (10, 'D'), (14, 'D')]
>>> sorted(t, key=lambda s=itemgetter(0):suits.count(s[1]), reverse=True) #Sort by most occurence of cards
[(11, 'D'), (12, 'D'), (13, 'D'), (10, 'D'), (14, 'D'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'C')]
```

Now, applying the above in your function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
def order_cards(order_by=suit):
    '''
    order_by has two arguments, either suit or number
    if suit: order by occurances of suit from largest to smallest
    if number: order by decreasing number
    '''
    t = zip(numbers,suits)    
    if order_by='number':
        lst = sorted(t, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
        ordered_cards = [x[0] for x in lst]
        return ordered_cards
    elif order_by='suit':
        lst = sorted(t, key=lambda s=itemgetter(0):suits.count(s[1]), reverse=True) 
        ordered_cards = [x[1] for x in t]
        return ordered_cards
    else:
        return '{} is not \'suit\' or \'number\''.format(order_by)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

zip the lists together to generate one list with tuples that combine the elements. this zipped list can easily be sorted. if you really need to have the sorted lists separated afterwards, generate them from the sorted combined list:

```
numbers = [11, 12, 13, 10, 14, 2, 3] 
suits = ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C']
combined = sorted(zip(numbers,suits))
numbers = [n for n,s in combined]
suits = [s for n,s in combined]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `zip` your two lists together, and sort the resultant cards with lambda that specifies which way you want to sort. This code sample sorts by the first item of the cards, which is the number value.

```
numerical_sort = sorted(card for card in zip(numbers, suits), key = lambda card: card[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to manipulate your lists as one:

```
numbers=[11, 12, 13, 10, 14, 2, 3] 
suits=['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C']

combined = zip(numbers, suits)  # [(11, 'D'), (12, 'D'), (13, 'D'), (10, 'D'), (14, 'D'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'C')]
```

> The first should order the lists numerically, from highest to lowest

```
sorted_list = sorted(combined, key= lambda x: x[0])
numbers = [fst for fst, _ in sorted_list]  # [2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
suits = [snd for _, snd in sorted_list]  # ['C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

> the second should order them by instances of suit occurrence, from most to least occurances in the list

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(suits)

sorted_list = sorted(combined, key= lambda x: count[x[1]], reverse=True)
numbers = [fst for fst, _ in sorted_list]  # [11, 12, 13, 10, 14, 2, 3]
suits = [snd for _, snd in sorted_list]  # ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'C']
```